# PDO sem suporte a JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

Estou precisando retornar uma linha em JSON, mas o PDO parece não dar suporte total às operações. Sempre a mensagem de erro *type 245*.

> PDO::prepare(): Unknown type 245 sent by the server. Please send a report to the developers

---

Testei no PDO um select simples `SELECT JSON_ARRAY('a', 1, NOW())` e só obtenho o erro sem maiores descrições, nem achei nada na DOC. O mesmo select na linha de comando no MYSQL retorna o que é esperado:

> ["a", 1, "2017-07-18 00:11:06.000000"]

---

Alguém tem uma referência pra ajudar a resolver isso?

Comment: Qual a versão do `PHP` e do `MySQL`?

Comment: Fui testar a função aqui no servidor da empresa, mas aqui e mariadb versão 10.1, https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/json_array/ então nem rola tentar ajudar kkk

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade PHP Version 5.5.0, MYSQL 5.7.13

Comment: @MarceloBoni, sem problema rs. Joguei no *sqlfiddle* pra testar e também retorna erro.

Comment: A versão do sqlfiddle é 5.6, as funções com suporte a `JSON` foram implementadas a partir do mysql 5.7 segundo a documentação

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme pode ver no bug tracking [#70384](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70384), foi corrigido nas versões PHP-5.6, PHP-7.0 e master (PHP-7.1).

O que você pode fazer para resolver momentaneamente é um `CAST` no retorno do `JSON`:

```
SELECT CAST(JSON_ARRAY('a', 1, NOW()) AS CHAR(255))
```

Comment: Confesso que não sabia dessa. Resolveu bem resolvido rs

Comment: Sabe se atualizar só a DLL resolve?

Comment: Acredito que sim, nas pesquisas que vi encontrei algo sobre as libs desatualizada. Vou tentar achar pra linkar aqui.